# work backwards to price the option at each nodes

Tags: matlab

I am trying to work backwards and price the option at each nodes in Matlab , but when I do it I don't get the right answer. I want to find the value of the call option at time 0. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

```
% generate the tree
K=100; r=0.05; delta=0.1; T=1; sigma=0.2; n=100; b=2; dt=1/3;
S1=130*ones(1,1); % stock price at time t = 0
S2=zeros(b,1); % stock price at time t = 1/3
S3=zeros(b*b,1); % stock price at time t = 2/3
S4=zeros(b*b*b,1); % stock price at time t = 1
t=[0;1/3;2/3;1];

for i=1:b
    z=normrnd(0,1);
    S2(i)=S1*exp((r-delta-(sigma)^2)*(dt)+sigma*sqrt(dt)*z);
end

for i=1:b
    for j=1:b
    z=normrnd(0,1);
    S3((i-1)*b+j)=S2(i)*exp((r-delta-(sigma)^2)*(dt)+sigma*sqrt(dt)*z);
    end
end

for i=1:b*b
    for j=1:b
    z=normrnd(0,1);
    S4((i-1)*b+j)=S3(i)*exp((r-delta-(sigma)^2)*(dt)+sigma*sqrt(dt)*z); 
    end
end

matrix=NaN*ones(size(S4,1),4);
%NaN=0;
matrix(1:size(S1,1),1)=S1;
matrix(1:size(S2,1),2)=S2;
matrix(1:size(S3,1),3)=S3;
matrix(1:size(S4,1),4)=S4;
S=[S1;S2;S3;S4];

% work backwards to price the option at each nodes
theta4=max(S4-K,0)
for i=1:length(S3)
    theta3(i)=max(S3(i)-K,exp(-r*(1/3))*theta4(i))
end
for i=1:length(S2)
    theta2(i)=max(S2(i)-K,exp(-r*(1/3))*theta3(i))
end
theta1=max(S1-K, exp(-r*(1/3))*theta2(i))
```

Comment: consider reorganize your question. Explain what you meant by "work backwards", what is price, option, nodes,  and time. Otherwise, without that context, no one knows what this code does or to be able to help you.